# What domain structure is best for a forum according to SEO?

Tags: seo, marketing, forum

I am running a website with PR2. On that site, I'd like to create a forum. For the domain structure I could either use:

www.forums.yourdomain.com
www.yourdomain.com/forums

According to SEO, what domain structure would be best? If I choose www.forums.yourdomain.com then it's a new subdomain with no PageRank (PR0) and if I choose www.yourdomain.com/forums then it's already a PR2 website. Can I also make my forum premium and earn through it? Will this decrease my PR2 site ranking? Kindly tell what your thoughts are on this ...

Comment: PageRank is per page, not for an entire site. PR2 is certainly PageRank of your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misconception about Pagerank.  It is assigned on a page by page basis, so any new URL will have pagerank 0 until it gets some links. That will be the case for either forums in a folder, or forums on a sub-domain.  Since you will be linking to your forum from the rest of your site, you will be passing pagerank to the forums whether they are a sub-directory or a sub-domain.

As for which is better for SEO, that is answered by this question: [How does google regard subdomains with regard to SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44624/how-does-google-regard-subdomains-with-regard-to-seo/)